# Hypothesis testing: Determining the size of a rejection region

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Given:

- $\langle x_n \rangle_{n=1}^N$ is a realization of a random sample $\langle X_n \rangle_{n=1}^N$ of  a normally distributed random variable $X$
- Null hypothesis, $H_0$: $E[X] = 0$ and var$(X)= 1$
- Test statistic, $T = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n$
- The rejection region is the closed interval $[-r,r]$, where $r$ is a parameter.

Determine

- r such that the probability of a type-1 error, i.e. rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true, is $0.05$.

Attempt:

Assume that $H_0$ is true, then the probability of rejecting $H_0$ satisfies
\begin{align}
 0.05 &= P (T\notin [-r,r]) \\
&=1 - P(T\in [-r,r]) \\
&=1- \int_{-r}^r\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\text{d}x\\
&=1 - \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)
\end{align}

How do I find $r$?

Comment: Wait. Is $Var(X)=1$ given, or part of $H_0$?

Comment: $var(X)$ is part of $H_0$. I am unsure how excluding it from $H_0$ affects the solution, and I would be grateful if you could teach me.

Comment: Is the population variance, i.e. $Var(X_i)$ known?

Comment: Yes, since $\langle X_n \rangle_{n=1}^N$ is a random sample of $X$ implies that $\forall n, var(X_n)=var(X)$.

Comment: $X_i$ are identically distributed, but $Var(X)$ itself is unkown...

Comment: For $H_0 : Var(X)=1$ you can use an F-test. if $Var(X)=1$ is verified, then you can build a confidence interval based on $z$-test.

Comment: The test statistic suggests the population variance is known, hence my query. Anyway, $T$ has a normal distribution and the equation should be $P(T\in[-r,r])=0.05$ when $H_0$ is true, from which $r$ can be found from a normal table or software. There is no error function or integration involved in the calculation; you only have to express the probability in terms of the standard normal cdf $\Phi$.

Comment: @Mick: Good point, what I meant is that if hypothesis $H_0$ is assumed to be true then we know both $var(X_i)$ and $var(X)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I understand what you mean by using a computer or table to find $r$. However, I am unsure about what you mean with population.

Comment: Your computations assume that $[-r,r]$ is the region of acceptance and not rejection. Giving a rejection region of the form $[-r,r]$ makes no sense.

Comment: @Angelos It is true that it does not matter in this calculation if $Var(X_i)$ is known or not. Could you confirm if the region of rejection given is correct?

Comment: I see what you mean now. The rejection region should be $[-r,r]^c$, i.e. we reject the hypothesis if the estimated mean is far from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under $H_0$, the distribution of $T$ is not standard normal. It is normal with zero mean and variance $$\text{Var}_{H_0}(T)\;\buildrel{\text{indep.}} \over = \;\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{n=1}^N \text{Var}_{H_0}(X_n) = \dfrac{N}{N^2} = \dfrac1N.$$
So $\sqrt{N}T$ is a standard normal r.v. Therefore
\begin{align}
 0.05 &= P (T\not\in [-r,r]) \\
&=1 - P(T\in [-r,r]) \\
&=1 - P\Bigl(\sqrt{N\mathstrut}T\in \left[-\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r,\;\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r\right]\Bigr) \\
&=1- \Bigl(\Phi\left(\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r\right) - \Phi\left(-\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r\right)\Bigr).
\end{align}
Here $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2}\,dt$ is the cdf of standard normal distribution. Next use properties of $\Phi(x)$: $\Phi(x)=1-\Phi(-x)$ and replace r.h.s. of the above equality by 
$$
0.05 = 2\Phi\left(-\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r\right), \qquad \Phi\left(-\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r\right) = 0.025.
$$
Then use tables or some computer tools to find argument $-\sqrt{N\mathstrut}r$ and then $r$.